# What is the position of an unmatched group in C++?

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

Let `m` be of type `std::smatch` . Suppose there is an unmatched group `i`. What is
`m.position(i)` ? For that matter, what is `m[i]`?

For example, consider

```
std::regex re {"^(a+)|(b+)"};
string target="aa";
std::smatch m;
std::regex_search(target,m,re);
cout<<"m[2] is: "<<m[2]<<" at position: "<<m.position(2);
```

I cannot figure out from the reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/position what is guaranteed to happen here and why.

Comment: It would be faster to write a test than to wait for someone who absolutely knows.

Comment: What do you get when you run that code?

Comment: @Barmar What possible difference would running the code make? I do not care what a particular set of compilers does; I care here what the standard requires.

Comment: How the regex should behave depends on the arguments you pass to the constructor for `std::regex`. In this case you're leaning on the default, which is ECMAScript, for which you can find some reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript). In a nutshell, you have 3 groups: the overall match, the (a+) and (b+)

Comment: @AndyG exactly and I am asking the standard requires the position of the (b+) match to be, since it fails to match.

Comment: @AndyG His point is that `(b+)` doesn't match anything, so what do all the functions that reference submatch 2 do?

Comment: I think you're supposed to use `m[2].matched` to tell if it matched anything.

Comment: And I'm saying that the behavior will be dependent on the (optional) flags used to construct `std::regex` is constructed. For example [nosubs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/syntax_option_type) will always result in  no matches being stored in `smatch`

Comment: @AndyG use the flags in the example please.

Comment: @Barmar thanks that is probably correct. But what happens if I don't check `.matched`?

Comment: @kdog: Given your exact code and input ("aa"), it's clear the 3rd group is not matched, so it will be an empty string.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be specified. I'd expect an invalid index like `-1`.

Comment: @AndyG `position` isn't a string, it's an index.

Comment: @Barmar: OP should check `m[2].empty()`

Comment: @AndyG I think you mean `m[2].str().empty()`

Comment: But you can also get an empty string when you match an empty substring, such as when using a quantifier. E.g. with `(a*)(b*)` you'll get an empty string with the position being `2`.

Comment: @JosephLarson: Results from tests gives hints, no guaranties. C++ has lot of UB, unspecified/implementation specific behaviors to avoid to rely only on tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the C++17 Standard:

> **28.10** `Class template match_results` **[** `re.results` **]**
>
> **4** The sub_match object stored at index 0 represents sub-expression 0, i.e., the whole match. In this case the sub_match member matched is always true. The sub_match object stored at index n denotes what matched the marked sub-expression n within the matched expression. If the sub-expression n participated in a regular expression match then the sub_match member matched evaluates to true, and members first and second denote the range of characters [first,second) which formed that match. Otherwise matched is false, and members first and second point to the end of the sequence that was searched.
>
> *[* Note: The sub_match objects representing different sub-expressions that did not participate in a regular expression match need not be distinct. — end note *]*

Now `m.position(n)` returns `(*this)[n].first`.

Given that *"[If] matched is false, [then] members first and second point to the end of the sequence that was searched"* ...

This means `m.position(n)` should point "to the end of the sequence that was searched".

Comment: That looks like a great answer and exactly what I was looking for. I do have a question: why wasn't this, or is it, somewhere convenient in cppreference? Should I not be using cppreference and instead only use the standard? I've been cheating by using cppreference all my life.

Comment: @kdog I find *cppreference* is much easier to search and understand than the standard. I would probably code at the pace of a snail if I went to the Standard for everything - especially basic API stuff. This is a little obscure as not many people are likely to need to know this information. Maybe that's why *cppreference* overlooked it? It is usually pretty accurate but no cooperatively edited website is going to be 100% all the time.  You pay your money and take your chance!

Comment: The reason cppreference is easier to read is precisely because it doesn't go into as much detail as the standard needs to.